# Unmatched values from two unix files

Tags: shell

I have two unix files with numeric values only such as :

File 1 :
12345
23456
234578

File 2 :
 2387
12345
23456
767888

I need to separate uncommon values from two files such as : 234578, 2387, 767888. And direct into one separate file using shell script. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sort  fileA fileB |uniq -u >fileC

Answer (score 0):

`comm` can be used to find the lines in the files unique to one of them.

```
sort file1.txt > file1.srt
sort file2.txt > file2.srt
comm -2 -3 file1.srt file2.srt > only1.txt
comm -1 -3 file1.srt file2.srt > only2.txt
```

Comment: add to the above: sort -u only1.txt only2.txt to get all the unique items. :)

Comment: Also, we can combine two files : cat only1.txt only2.txt > uniq :-)